# Two way data binding not working from subscribe in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components, angular-observable

I am subscribing to a subject in Angular, on value change, I am trying to change a variable value in the component. In the console, the value shows an update, but on the view(HTML), it doesn't.

**Service.ts**

```
    export class GMapsService {
  public mysubject: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  getData(or, des) {
    var origin1 = or;
    var destinationA = des;
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    var self = this;

    service.getDistanceMatrix(
      {
        origins: [origin1],
        destinations: [destinationA],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: true,
      },
      (response, status) => {
        // this.mysubject.next(response);

        setInterval(
          function () {
            self.mysubject.next(Math.random())
          },
          2000
        )
      }
    );


  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title: any = 'app';

  constructor(private GMapsService: GMapsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.GMapsService.getData('dallas, tx', 'austin, tx');

    this.GMapsService.mysubject.subscribe((value) => {
      this.title = value;
      console.log(this.title);       
 //title is random number in console. ex: 0.4333333
 //title is still 'app' on view till now.
    });

setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.title);
    }, 5000);


//title is random number in console.  ex: 0.4333333
// title suddenly become 'random number  ex: 0.4333333' on view after it is logged after 5 secs. How does logging 'title' again after 5 seconds change its value?
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
{{title}}
```

I believe, if the same value is changing in the console, it should reflect on the view part as well. On other questions, it says, I am missing this context, but the value is getting updated in the console, so I believe I am not missing the context.

**Edit**: I tried logging title after 5 seconds, and it suddenly changes on the view. How can just logging the value change it on the view?

Comment: Please post your view

Comment: @ShakeerHussain done

Comment: My guess: `this.title` has the wrong scope. So `this` is not referencing to your component. Try to add a console.log or breakpoint in there. Not quite sure, but maybe you could write `this.GMapsService.mysubject.subscribe(value => this.title = value);`

Comment: Can you move the line `this.GMapsService.getData('dallas, tx', 'austin, tx');` below the subscription line? I mean, subscribe first then call the function.

Comment: I think you had missed declaring access modifier e.g.:                           Public title: any = 'app';

Comment: @ShakeerHussain The default modifier is public in typescript anyway

Comment: for a code standards in typescript use any for your subscribe value like subscribe((value: any)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using a basic Subject, you need to subscribe to the subject before you receive the data from a synchronous call (which getDistanceMatrix should not be unless you mocked it). That is, because basic Subjects don't replay the last published values by default.

If you want to avoid this, you can use a ReplaySubject or a BehaviorSubject:

*service.ts*

```
@Injectable()
export class GMapsService {
  public mysubject: ReplaySubject<any> = new ReplaySubject(1);

  getData(or, des) {
    var origin1 = or;
    var destinationA = des;
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

    service.getDistanceMatrix(
      {
        origins: [origin1],
        destinations: [destinationA],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: true,
      },
      (response, status) => {
        console.log('service callback');
        this.mysubject.next(response);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

*component.ts*

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title: any = 'app';

  constructor(private GMapsService: GMapsService, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.GMapsService.getData('dallas, tx', 'austin, tx');

    this.GMapsService.mysubject.subscribe((value) => {
      this.title = value;
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });
  }
}
```

Working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m578et?file=app%2Fgmaps.service.ts)

EDIT: Apparently, the google `DistanceMatrixService.getDistanceMatrix` response doesn't trigger the change detection. Try to use a `ChangeDetectorRef` and manually look for Changes. I changed the code example accordingly.

ADDENDUM: Angular uses a change detection system that hooks into typical triggers of asynchronous events to detect which parts of the view have to be updated. Examples for triggers are user inputs, timers (setTimeout, setInterval) or Websocket events. If the Google DistanceMatrixService uses a way to retrieve the data that doesn't trigger angular's change detection system, the data for the view is not checked for changes and therefore not updated properly. Since `setTimeout` triggers the change detection, it was working when you used `setTimeout`. You can read more about the angular change detection system [here](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html).

Comment: Hey, thanks. This doesn't work for me, when I pass the actually API :(

Comment: None. I just realized my code works fine when I check the variable after 5 seconds,  on settimeout the value changes on the view. I updated my code as well. Could you please check it?

Comment: Using timeouts to update the view isn't recommended. Can you add a `console.log` to your component's subscription and tell me if it gets logged?

Comment: Yes it does. For example in subscription the value assigned is 0.4. Now if I log the same value in settimeout it is still 0.4 but now it gets updated on the view. I'm confused how can just logging update the view?

Comment: Hey, that change detector got it working thanks! But I am still confused, how come when the title value is updating in the console, not updating in the view? And why does just logging it in settimeout update it on the view?

Comment: I added a brief explanation to the answer.